# How to run orca from R?

Tags: r, npm, plotly

I have installed [orca](https://github.com/plotly/orca#installation) using npm and if I go to my R project folder and type `orca --version`, I see `1.3.1`.

In Rstudio I have installed the `processx` package.  Having produced a `fig` with `plot_ly` if I try capture a plot I see the following

```
orca(fig, 'temp.svg')

Error in processx::run("orca", "-h") : 
  System command 'orca' failed, exit status: 127, stderr:
E> env: node: No such file or directory
Type .Last.error.trace to see where the error occurred
```

If I type `.Last.error.trace` I see the following

```
Stack trace:

 1. plotly:::orca(fig, "temp.svg")
 2. plotly:::orca_available()
 3. plotly:::correct_orca()
 4. processx::run("orca", "-h")
 5. throw(new_process_error(res, call = sys.call(), echo = echo,  ...

 x System command 'orca' failed, exit status: 127, stderr:
E> env: node: No such file or directory
```

I have restarted Rstudio and restarted R, but still see the problem. How do I fix this?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1741) you can find some related information.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I assume that you already installed both **orca and processx library**. The next steps are:

1. install standalone **Orca desktop app** and
2. Makes the path of the installation **accessible** from Rstudio

You may skip the step one and directly go to the second step since you mentioned that you already installed the desktop app using NPM. However, **I recommend you** to reinstall it as I did.

For doing **step one** with regular installation method, you can download Orca installer (windows-release.zip) from github: [orca installer](https://github.com/plotly/orca/releases/download/v1.3.1/windows-release.zip). Then, install the app inside the zip folder.

After installing it, you can go to **the second step** by doing:

1. Find your Orca app displayed on your desktop, right-click on the orca icon and select Properties from the context menu.
2. From the Shortcut tab, copy the directory in the Start in field.
   (you need this for adding the app's PATH later in step-7).
3. hit "windows logo + X" to open Power-User menu, go to SETTING
4. go to ABOUT, click the Advanced system settings
5. click the Advanced tab, then click the Environment Variables button near the bottom of that tab
6. highlight the Path variable in the SYSTEM VARIABLES section and click the Edit button
7. Add path lines by paste your installation path (from step-2)

Restart your PC to ensure everything runs smoothly.

Finally, you can try your code again in Rstudio. Hope this can help some confusions.

Comment: I should have mentioned I am using a Mac OSX 12.2.1.

Comment: I guess the intention is the same, you need to grant access to the installation path since the error message was "env: node: No such file or directory". 
Sorry, I don't have any clue to link the path on Mac since I dont have a Mac, but I had a similar problem before using Windows and solved it using those methods